# Finding f'(x) , Differentiation problem

Tags: derivatives

$(a)$ Use the formal definition of the derivative to compute $ f'(2) $ when $ f(x)=\frac{1-x}{2x} $

$(b)$ Do the same to find $f'(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write, as $x \to 2$,
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\frac{\frac{1-x}{2x}-\frac{(-1)}{4}}{x-2}=\frac{\frac{-(x-2)}{4x}}{x-2}=-\frac1{4x} \to -\frac1{8}
$$ Similarly, to get $f'(x)$, one may consider, as $h \to 0$,
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$